# Line Search ABC

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I apologize in advance if this sounds silly or too basic, but I could not find any definitive answer elsewhere:

Is multi-dimensionality the only reason why I need to implement a line search to find a minimum of a vector-based function, as opposed to a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ , where if I want to find a minimum of $f$, I calculate the first derivative $f'$, equal it to zero, and solve the equation for $x$? 
I'd appreciate being pointed to a clear (textbook?) explanation of this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the multi-dimensionality is not the reason why you sometimes want to use a line search algorithm. You could use the exact same approach for a function $f(x)$ with a multi-dimensional $x$, just compute the derivative (assuming you can derive it), just solve $f'(x) = 0$. And you will have found a local extremum or a saddle point.

Note that you will have found a local minimum or a local maximum or a saddle point : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point . Checking if what you found is actually a minimum involve computing the second derivative (same as in one dimension).

In practice, solving $f'(x) = 0$ may be more difficult when $x$ is multi-dimensional, but it depend more on your function $f'$ (and $f''$ if you want to avoid saddle points).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That cleared some of my doubts. However, could you please elaborate a little on why , then, should one perform a line search if derivation can get you to the same result? As I understand it, line search is a numerical approximation of the solution, while derivation gives an exact solution. In other words, when are we forced to use line search?

Comment: Derivation will give exact solution as long as you can solve it exactly. Many equations $g(x) = 0$ cannot be solved exactly and you need to use a numerical approximation to use the solution.  So, you don't *have* to use line search, but the algorithms may be faster or easier to set up in your specific situation.